# Redraw plot once if one reactive value changes but not the other?

Tags: r, shiny

I have two reactive values `input$code` and `input$variants` and I want to redraw the plot once if any of the following conditions are true.

1. code changes and variants changes
2. code changes and variants does not change
3. code does not change and variants changes

I can't call both `input$code` and `input$variants` in renderPlotly or else the plot will get redrawn twice for #1 above.

---

```
  output$choose_test <- renderUI({
    data_sets <- loadTest()
    selectizeInput(
      'test', 'Test', choices = data_sets$test, selected = data_sets$test[1]
    )
  })

  output$choose_code <- renderUI({
    validate(
      need(input$test, 'Please choose a test.')
    )

    code <- loadCode(input$test)
    selectizeInput(
      'code', 'Code', choices = code$code, selected = code$code[1]
    )
  })

  output$choose_variants <- renderUI({
    validate(
      need(input$test,  'Please choose a test.'),
      need(input$code,   'Please choose a code.')
    )

    dat <- loadVariants(input$test, input$code)

    default_select <- dat$variant[grep('v1|v2', dat$variant)]
    if (identical(default_select, factor(0))) {
      default_select <- dat$variant[1]
    }

    checkboxGroupInput("variants", "Variants",
                        choices  = dat$variant,
                        selected = default_select)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({

    runLocations <- isolate(loadRunsBetweenDates(input$test, input$code, input$variants))

    total_min_df <-
      runLocations %>%
      group_by(change_number, variant) %>%
      summarize(memory = min(memory))

    total_min_df$change_number <- as.numeric(as.character(total_min_df$change_number))

    p <- ggplot(total_min_df,
           aes(x=change_number,
               y=memory,
               group=variant,
               color=variant))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(se = FALSE)+
    scale_x_continuous(labels = function(n){format(n, scientific = FALSE)})+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = function(n){format(n, scientific = FALSE)})+
    labs(x = "Change Number", y = "Megabytes")

    ggplotly(p)
  })
```

Comment: It's pretty unclear to me what you are asking. It would be helpful to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that more clearly demonstrates your question. I'm not sure how you are even simultaneously changing two values.

Comment: @MrFlick edited to include part of server.R

Comment: @Takkun I agree with MrFlick on the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: How can the first case happen, I mean how can both variables change at the same time or at least as the result of one single event?